# node js sql output

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I am trying to come up with the node.js code to get the output of this query:

```
const viewAllEmployees = () => {
let sql = 'SELECT e.id, e.first_name, e.Last_name, r.title, d.name as "Department", salary, CONCAT (m.first_name," ", m.last_name) AS "Manager" 
FROM employee e '  + connection.escape('INNER JOIN employee m 
ON e.manager_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN role r 
ON e.role_id = r.id 
LEFT JOIN department d 
on r.department_id = d.id');
    connection.query(sql, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.table(res);
    // console.log(res);
    //connection.end();
  });
```

The problem is that when I use it without the connection.escape(), I get the output, but with single quotes like this:

[image]

How can I (1) get rid of the (index) column, and (2) get rid of the single quotes?
Getting rid of the single quotes is really the priority.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index column and quotes are added by `console.table` function itself.

You can check it running console.table with any static data like here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table#collections_of_primitive_types

To print it in a way you want it, implement printing function on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eugene.  Your answer is what I was looking for.